# Guardar Imagen en SQL Server mediante PictureBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Buen día, estoy trabajando con una aplicación dentro de C#, la cual funciona como un inventario para los equipos dentro de la empresa. Estoy trabajando dentro de Windows Forms.

Lo que pretendo hacer es guardar los registros de cada computadora, con su respectiva imagen para su localización mas fácil.

Cabe mencionar que el campo de la base de datos lo declare como image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como estoy cargando la imagen dentro del PictureBox:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog getImage = new OpenFileDialog();
            getImage.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            getImage.Filter = "Archivos de Imagen (*.jpg)(*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG(*.png)|*.png";
            if (getImage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = getImage.FileName;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

De esta forma los pretendo meter a la base de datos:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" || comboBox1.Text != "" || comboBox2.Text != "")
            {

                SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Equipos values ((RTRIM(LTRIM(" + textBox1.Text + "))), (RTRIM(LTRIM('" + variable + "'))),  (RTRIM(LTRIM('" + textBox3.Text + "'))) ,(RTRIM(LTRIM('" + textBox2.Text + "'))), (RTRIM(LTRIM('" + comboBox1.Text + "'))), (RTRIM(LTRIM('" + comboBox2.Text + "'))), (RTRIM(LTRIM('" + textBox10.Text + "'))), @Imagen)", cadena);
                try
                {
                    cadena.Open();

                    agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Agregado");

                    Variables.equipos1 = textBox1.Text;
                    Variables.equipos2 = variable;
                    Variables.equipos3 = textBox2.Text;
                    Variables.equipos4 = comboBox1.Text;
                    Variables.equipos5 = comboBox2.Text;
                    Variables.equipos6 = textBox10.Text;
                    Variables.dialogo = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cadena.Close();
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                cadena.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("No puede dejar vacio");

                textBox2.Clear();
            }
        }
```

El error que me muestra al ejecutarlo asi es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente cuando trabajo con winforms convierto la imagen a un array de bytes con una función como a continuación te muestro:

```
    public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imagen)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imagen.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Ahora para obtener el valor y asignarlo podrías hacer así:

```
  byte[] byteArrayImagen = ImageToByteArray(PictureBox1.Image)
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
  command.Text="INSERT INTO TABLA (CAMPO) values (@imagen)";
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen",byteArrayImagen);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Alfredo, una ultima pregunta, como hago para digamos una vez guardada mostrarla en un picture box?

Comment: Depende mucho de como estés extrayendo los datos. Yo por ejemplo utilizo Entity Framework, por lo que solo tengo que hacer el proceso inverso y convertir el array de bytes en imagen de la siguiente forma: 

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            
Pero para recomendarte bien tendría que ver el código que utilizas para recuperar la información de base de datos. Saludos!